# searching text with regexp in a large database

Tags: mysql, regex, text

i'm trying to use this query script to search a mysql database
http://www.ar-php.org/Examples/ArQuery.php

i'm only searching one column in the table.. but each row has around 3000 characters long text in that column.. i've only added 100 rows right now, but it slowed down already..

if i have one million rows like this, would this script be unusable?

what route should i take in order to be able to use this script and have millions of row with long texts..

my queries look like this:

SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE ( REPLACE(text, 'ـ', '') REGEXP '(كَ|كِ|كُ|كً|كٍ|كٌ|كْ|كّ|كَّ|كِّ|كُّ|كًّ|كٍّ|كٌّ|ك)(يَ|يِ|يُ|يً|يٍ|يٌ|يْ|يّ|يَّ|يِّ|يُّ|يًّ|يٍّ|يٌّ|ي)(فَ|فِ|فُ|فً|فٍ|فٌ|فْ|فّ|فَّ|فِّ|فُّ|فًّ|فٍّ|فٌّ|ف)')

SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE ( REPLACE(text, 'ـ', '') REGEXP 'hell(ö|o|ô|Ö|O|Ô)')

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Which character set and collation does the column have? Use the right one [during select query] and you don't need this regexp.

Comment: my default is utf8_general_ci

Comment: If you already use `utf8_unicode_ci` (and `utf8` as character set), then `SELECT 'ö' = 'ô'` returns `1` and `'hellÖ' = 'hellô'` as well!

Comment: yes but that is if i use LIKE, right? i need to use regexp for other cases where LIKE wouldn't match.. for example ه = ة at the end of the word..

Answer (score 2):

@ali haydar

i definitely suggest to use [Full Text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index and related MySql functions. Regexs are good and efficient for relatively small texts but not for searching inside database. Full text index is designed for such purposes and uses extremely efficient data structures to minimize disk I/O and search quickly inside large data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i'm considering full text search, but how can i use the regexp flexibility with it, i'm not sure.. so is a large database with regexp queries like this impossible?

Comment: although these are not same as regexs but you canexploit capabilities of boolean mode operators http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html